# Installing packages from a list using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a list of packages using pip.

The code which I used is:

```
import pip

def install(package_name):
        try:
            pip.main(['install', package_name])
        except:
            print("Unable to install " + package_name)
```

This code works fine and if a package is not available, it gives an error:

> No matching distributions found

However, what I am trying to do is if an installation fails (for eg: invalid package name), I want to print the package which failed.

What can be done for that?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/21be153044a7aa245e12ce3f86793e9b17201519/pip/index.py#L525

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking the return value for non-zero, which indicates an error occurred with the install. Not all errors trigger exceptions.

```
import pip

def install(package_name):
        try:
            pipcode = pip.main(['install', package_name])
            if pipcode != 0:
                print("Unable to install " + package_name + " ; pipcode %d" % pipcode)
        except:
            print("Unable to install " + package_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of package to verify if no matching distribution was find. Normally the package will return 0 if exists a installation candidate, otherwise will return 1 for no candidate found

```
import pip

def install(package_name):
    package = pip.main(['install', package_name])      
    result = "Package successfully installed: " if package == 0 else "Unable to find package: "
    print(result + package_name)
```

So, if you try to do something like this:

```
>>> install("Virtualenvs")
```

Will return:

```
Collecting virtualenvs
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvs (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenvs
Unable to find package: virtualenvs
```

Because there's no valid package for "Birtualenvs". But with a valid package:

```
>>> install("virtualenv")
```

Will return:

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Package successfully installed: virtualenv
```

Comment: The `try-except` `else` block executes if there is no exception. In this case, there is no exception, because the error code is returned by the `pip.main()` method. In this case, I think you're forced to check for an error code in the return value, because otherwise you'll print the "Unable to install" message for a successful install.

Comment: You are right, even when I set a valid package its was returning the messenger for no valid package found