# How can I install a library in script as well as importing it?

Tags: python, pip, python-import

I want to test in script whether all the necessary libraries are installed or not, if not, install it. Here is my code:

```
libs = ['lib1','lib2','lib3']
def import_m(name):
    try:
        import name 
    except:
        pip.main(['install',name])
        import name                    #look at this line
for i in libs:
        import_m(i)
print("Done importing %s." % i)
```

But when running it raise an exection:

```
ImportError: No module named name
```

The line mentioned with this exection are indicated by the comment.

How can I fix it?

Comment: start with checking the return value of pip.main

Comment: @tkhurana96 What do you mean by **return value** ?

Comment: have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799042/installing-packages-from-a-list-using-pip)

Comment: @tkhurana96 It does return 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code).
The error says `No module named name`, even though you're actually installing `lib1`, `lib2` and `lib3`. `import name` literally imports `name`, not the value of the `name` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going to need

> importlib

for this functionality.

A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661188/import-files-in-python-with-a-for-loop-and-a-list-of-names)

For your requirement you can first try to import a library using

> globals()['module_name'] = importlib.import_module('module_name')

if it throws an exception you just need to install it and run the above code again. Don't try to run `import module_name` again. If `module_name` is successfully stored in globals you are all good to go.